What's the equivalent to $\in$ notation for proper classes?
If I want to write that $n$ is a natural number, I'd write $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Likewise, if I want to state that something applies to all natural numbers or to at least one, I'd write the equation as $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ or $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}$. Or for the real numbers, I'd use $\mathbb{R}$.
However, those only work because the natural and real numbers are both sets. But, ZFC doesn't allow all conceivable collections to be made into a set. The proper class I had in mind when writing this was "ordinal numbers", but there's also non-empty sets, power sets, finite size sets, infinite rank sets, and of course, all sets.
But suppose I want to write a statement about all ordinal numbers, or that some ordinal number exists with X property. Could I use the same notation, like:
$\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{O} : \alpha+1=\bigcup\{\alpha, \{\alpha\}\}$
where $\alpha\in\mathbb{O}$ is a shorthand for "$\alpha$ is an ordinal number"? Or is the notation different when talking about membership in a proper class, rather than membership in a set?

Yes, it's normal to use that notation for classes.

All the proper classes you have in mind are definable by some predicate. For instance you won't write $\alpha\in\mathbb{O}$ but $On(\alpha)$, where $On(x)$ is some formula saying "$x$ is well-ordered by $\in$".
